# Component Query finds static config but not programmatically added

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

In our **ExtJs 5.0.1** project we create components and at **runtime** we add additional **css classes** conditional.
We want to **find them by a component query** but the component query **returns nothing** for the programatically added css classes.

But when we define them hardcoded in the component config then the query returns the expected result.

How can we get references to the components with programatically added css classes?

Example View:

```
Ext.define('T.view.Main',{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: 'test',
    cls: 'working', // static config

    initComponent: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.addCls('notworking'); // added at runtime
    }
});
```

Example Application:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'T',
    autoCreateViewport: 'T.view.Main',

    launch: function(){
        // the cls "working" assigned as config to the Main View is found by 
        // the ComponentQuery
        var working = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[cls~=working]');
    
        // the cls "notWorking" assigned by addCls during runtime to the Main View 
        // is not found by the ComponentQuery
        var notWorking = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[cls~=notworking]');
    
        Ext.Msg.alert('Static vs Dynamic', 'working: ' + working.length + ' notWorking: ' + notWorking.length);
    }
});
```

---

### Update

@Alexander suggested to add the additional cls before the callParent call  , which sounds like an obvious solution but now even the `.working` cls is not found by the component query.

```
Ext.define('T.view.Main',{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: 'test',
    cls: 'working', // static config

    initComponent: function(){
        this.cls += ' notworking';
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

See the updated [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11v6).

### Update 2

I may found the problem in the Component.js code, in the constructor the following happens

```
constructor: function (config) {
    ...
    me.setupProtoEl();

    // initComponent, beforeRender, or event handlers may have set the style or `cls` property since the `protoEl` was set up
    // so we must apply styles and classes here too.
    if (me.cls) {
        me.initialCls = me.cls;
        me.protoEl.addCls(me.cls);
    }
    if (me.style) {
        me.initialStyle = me.style;
        me.protoEl.setStyle(me.style);
    }

    me.renderData = me.renderData || {};

    me.initComponent();
    ...
```

1. the proto el is initialized with some css classes by `me.setupProtoEl();`
2. it is checked if `cls` is set and it is then applied to the proto element and saved to initialCls property
3. initComponent function is called, when `cls` is changed in it, it is not noticed by the constructor anymore

In my opinion the steps 2 and 3 needs to be swapped in order to recognize changes of `cls` in the initComponent function.

Comment: I know it does not answer the actual question but since debugging into ComponentQuery seems almost impossible as a workaround you could simply use Ext.query('.working') which returns the object in both cases for me. Btw: There is a typo in your initComponent method which prevents it from getting executed but I guess that's only in your example.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the example and fiddle and tried Ext.query . But it returns either the HTMLElement or Ext.dom.Element and not the actual ExtJs component.
I will keep it in mind as a workaround.

Comment: As I mentioned below, the cls configuration is not used post initialisation. A lot of the configuration values aren't read-write.

Comment: As I understand the initComponent function it is for initializing the components config before the callParent call. But for cls it is not working because of the wrong order in the component constructor, as i mentioned in the secound update above. This sounds like a bug of ExtJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobertWatkins points out the cls of the component is not changed by `addCls`, it just updates the DOM element.

A solution to set the `cls` config during runtime, is to do it in the components constructor. The cls is then applied to the DOM element and to the component aswell. The component query is now able to find it.

```
cls: 'working',
constructor: function (config) {
    this.cls += ' nowworking';
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
```

The corresponding application snippet

```
// the component is retrieved 
var working = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[cls~=working]');
// the component is retrieved aswell
var nowWorking = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[cls~=nowworking]');
```

A working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/122r).

Answer (score 3):

`cls` is a configuration attribute for you to specify the CSS class. But `addCls` doesn't update it - it simply updates the class attribute on the underlying DOM element.

```
addCls: function(cls) {
    var me = this,
        el = me.rendered ? me.el : me.protoEl;

    el.addCls.apply(el, arguments);
    return me;
},
```

([source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/source/Component.html#Ext-Component-cfg-cls))

Because `addCls` doesn't update the `cls` attribute, your ComponentQuery call can't find it that way.

As to how you solve your problem: the simplest way would be to add a property of your own on the class that you update at the same time as you add the class. Then you can do a component query on your custom property. Though I'd include the xtype of your class, so as to avoid potential namespace conflicts.

Comment: Hm we need to use the cls and not a custom property to apply styling to them. Maybe an additional custom property and cls would be a solution.

Comment: @RobertWatkins I have experimented with adding the line `this.cls = this.cls + ' notworking';` after the `addCls` call, but this does not work as well.

Comment: Use the cls to define the initial class, then use the custom property _and_ addCls to indicate that it's not working.

Simply changing the cls attribute once the component is initialised won't do anything much.